# Problem with Safe Wallet - Gnosis Safe Account send funds to Polygon to same wallet address

Tags: safe-core

I have created a safe wallet on gnosis network with metamask and Ledger. Everything worked. Then I thought, I can send EURe to the same gnosis wallet address in polygon network. Unfortunately that was wrong and I now want to know how I can generate the same wallet address in polygon network so that I can access my tokens.

I already checked the video on loom, but this is from ETH to polygon. My first creating transaction on gnosis have a different contract address that differs on polygon. So i did not follow the instractions in the video to not mess up everything.

I asked help.safe.global and in the chat the helper referred me here, to ask for help. I have ~4k$ stuck :-/

Sorry for my english.
best regards
mike

EDIT:
Louis helped me to create a safe on Polygon. Now I need to move my tokens with the safe-cli and Ledger.

Edited for better visibility of the output from safe-cli

```
... (output from safe-cli cuted)
Ledger=Connected
Safe is not updated! You can use update command to update the Safe to a newest version
blockchain > 0xC471f3707... > send_erc20 0xA7... 0x18... 1
Cannot find enough owners to sign. 1 missing
blockchain > 0xC4... > load_ledger_cli_owners --derivation-path m/44'/60'/0'/0/30
Loaded account 0x1b... with balance=x.xxx ether.
Ledger account cannot be defined as sender
blockchain > 0xC4... > send_erc20 0xA7... 0x18... 1
Make sure in your ledger before signing that domain_hash and message_hash are both correct
Domain_hash: dd5...
Message_hash: f39...
Please load a default sender
blockchain > 0xC4... >
```

Can someone help me to get this also done? I don't know why my Ledger cannot be defined as sender (see output in code box).
The --derivation-path m/44'/60'/0'/0/30 is correct, because it is loading the correct Ledger address "0x1b...".

Thanks for help!
Best regards
mike

Answer (score 0):

I understand this must be quite stressful, but hopefully we should be able to fix the situation. What we want to do is to deploy a Safe on Polygon with the exact same parameters than the one on Gnosis.

One important part is the `saltNonce` parameter used to calculate your Safe address on Gnosis. If you manage to find it, then it should be easy to deploy a new one on Polygon with the Safe{Core} SDK, using the same parameter.

Did you create your first Safe using our UI or the SDK?

Hope it helps, Louis

Comment: I can't find the saltNonce in the transaction because of the Gelato contract exec

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks! I have successfully created the safe on polygon. Now can you help me with the steps I nned to do with the cli to move the EURe? Because the UI will not Verify the Transaction. I tested it with 1 EURe to Crosschain back to gnosis with Monerium.

Comment: And the safe UI will not display the EURe asset. So I can't make a normal polygon transaction.

Comment: Hi Louis, can you help further? I got safe-cli working with Ledger but something is not working "Ledger account cannot be defined as sender" ....

Comment: with help from safe support, i got access to my EURe! Sending a small amount of EURe 0.10 to the Polygon address made the Safe-UI show the Token and I was able to send my 4k EURe with the UI to a new address. Thank you safe support team!

Comment: Happy you got this, and thanks for letting others know! I'm glad we could help. Best, Louis